# How do find snowy taiga biomes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have always wanted to find a snowy taiga biome, but I can not find any of them. I have only ever found one snowy taiga, but I did not have much time to explore it because I was in the demo. Also, I do not know what they look like on AMIDST. Is there a way to always find a snowy taiga?

Answer (score 3):

Biomes are generated randomly. The short answer is to keep walking, and you will eventually find one.

There are a few things you can do to improve your odds though:

- Best way: Use a seed. Just [find a seed](http://www.reddit.com/r/minecraftseeds) that starts you off in or near a taiga biome.
- Next best way: map your current seed. You can map your seed with a mapping program like [Amidst](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v36-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder-174/). This will allow you to easily find where the taiga biomes are. You can output your seed by hittng <kbd>t</kbd> and entering `/seed`.
- Least cheaty way: Look for neighbouring biomes. Recently, biomes can only border other similar biomes. A desert cannot be next to a taiga biome for example. If you head towards 'colder' biomes in your exploration, you will be more likely to find a taiga than if you explore near deserts.

Comment: I have recently found cold taigas that are next to jungles.

Answer (score 2):

The only 100% way to make sure you always find a [cold taiga](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome/Cold_Taiga) biome is if you get a seed that spawns you in that biome, otherwise biomes are generated randomly.

On [AMIDST](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v36-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder-174/), cold taiga biomes look like this

[image: Screenshot of AMIDST]

You just need to roll your mouse over each biome to find the one you are looking for.

Comment: What color is it, because I am looking at it on my kindle paperwhite, which is black and white

Comment: @HugoDodd It is white...

Comment: I mean the COLD TAIGA!!!

Comment: @HugoDodd Its like a dark aqua colour. Where my mouse is in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

In Minecraft 1.8 you can choose which biome you want your world to be
by going to "new world" then clicking the "world type" button until it
says "custom" then click the "customise" button, scrolling down two
the "world type" slider and changing it to "cold tagia".

You can use Minecraft 1.8 by going to the launcher, clicking "edit
profile" then clicking "allow use of experimental versions ("snapshots")" then "use version" then click "use latest version" and then "save profile" and "play". Now you are using Minecraft 1.8!

Answer (score 1):

Since Minecraft worlds are generated randomly, you could find a seed to use when generating the world. You could use things like MCedit to look around. There's also a locate command, but I'm not sure that works for biomes.